# PHP Array not correctly pulling data from php file

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm a bit stuck on this code. It worked "before" on a different site but now for some reason it does not work for this new one I am working on.  I have a separate PHP file that I store meta title, meta description, meta keywords, h1, h2 tags in as an array. The website is supposed to fetch that information divy up into variables and then it is placed in the correct positions within the code. Here is the code as follows:

SEO.PHP File in the root folder of the website

```
        <?php
       $meta['INDEX']['title']            = "Title";
       $meta['INDEX']['keywords']         = "keywords";
       $meta['INDEX']['description']      = "description";
       $meta['INDEX']['H1']            = "h1";
       $meta['INDEX']['H2']            = "h2";

       $meta['ABOUT']['title']            = "About Company";
       $meta['ABOUT']['keywords']         = "kwd1, kwd2, kwd3";
       $meta['ABOUT']['description']      = "About company description";
       $meta['ABOUT']['H1']            = "h1 title";

       $meta['SERVICES']['title']         = "About Company";
       $meta['SERVICES']['keywords']      = "kwd1, kwd2, kwd3";
       $meta['SERVICES']['description']   = "About company description";
       $meta['SERVICES']['H1']             = "h1 title";

       $meta['BLOG']['title']              = "About Company";
       $meta['BLOG']['keywords']           = "kwd1, kwd2, kwd3";
       $meta['BLOG']['description']       = "About company description";
       $meta['BLOG']['H1']                 = "h1 title";
     ?>
```

Example of code in INDEX.PHP

```
    <?php 
      include 'seo.php'; 
      $page_index = array_keys($meta);
      foreach($page_index as $page)
     {
       if ( strpos( strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), $page ) !== false)
     {
       $title        = $meta[$page]['title'];
       $keywords     = $meta[$page]['keywords'];
       $description = $meta[$page]['description'];
       $h1           = $meta[$page]['H1'];
       $h2           = $meta[$page]['H2'];
       break;
      }
      } ?>

      <!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html>
       <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
         <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
         <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
         <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>">
```

Here is what is printed out from the various variables for troubleshooting.

```
  print_r ($page_index);
Array ( [0] => INDEX [1] => ABOUT [2] => SERVICES [3] => BLOG )


print_r($meta);
Array ( [INDEX] => Array ( [title] => Plumbers in Birmingham, AL | Birmingham Plumbers 
[keywords] => Plumbers in Birmingham AL, Birmingham Plumbers, Plumbers Birmingham AL, 
Plumber Birmingham AL, Plumbing Birmingham Al, Hoover Plumbing, Plumbers in Hoover Al 
[description] => Plumbers in Birmingham, AL - Servicing Mountain Brook, Vestavia 
Hills, Hoover, Pelham, Alabaster, Helena, Homewood and more locations. [H1] => The 
Best Plumbers in Birmingham, AL [H2] => 24 Hour Emergency Plumbing Service ) [ABOUT] 
=> Array ( [title] => About Company [keywords] => kwd1, kwd2, kwd3 [description] => 
About company description [H1] => h1 title ) [SERVICES] => Array ( [title] => About 
Company [keywords] => kwd1, kwd2, kwd3 [description] => About company description [H1] 
=> h1 title ) [BLOG] => Array ( [title] => About Company [keywords] => kwd1, kwd2, 
kwd3 [description] => About company description [H1] => h1 title ) )
```

These print nothing at all...

```
print_r ($title);
print_r ($keywords);
print_r ($description);
print_r ($h1);
print_r ($h2);
```

And finally....

```
print_r ($page);
```

displays BLOG

So, I can see that the code is reading the php file and can read the array as can be seen with meta and page index.

But it is breaking down on the variables and also the page. Since this was tested on the index page and not the blog page - yet it returns blog.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check what is in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: Yeah its displaying just / - I set it up for the about page just now and it displays fine there. So the problem is it is not reading index.php as index but as just /

Comment: Are you using `mod_rewrite` (.htaccess or something)?

Comment: Yes, but done tried removing the mod_rewrite from htaccess to see if that would fix it but it did not fix anything. The htaccess is as follows.RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Comment: Give an example of the URL for these pages.

Comment: Does `include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/seo.php' );` work?

Comment: document_root does not work.   it works fine on all pages other than the index page AbraCadaver. Example Site.com/about (works fine), site.com/services (works fine).  I'm looking to see if I can utilize __FILE__ but trying to figure out how to strip the full path atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this (try `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` or `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` with `basename()`:

```
if ( strpos( basename(strtoupper($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])), $page ) !== false)
```

Or maybe:

```
if ( strpos( basename(strtoupper($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])), $page ) !== false)
```

Or to provide a default value you can try (might tweak what `$_SERVER` var you use here as well):

```
$page_index = array_keys($meta);
$vars = $meta['INDEX'];

foreach($page_index as $page){
    if ( strpos( strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), $page ) !== false) {
        $vars = $meta[$page];
        break;
    }
}
$title        = $vars['title'];
$keywords     = $vars['keywords'];
$description  = $vars['description'];
$h1           = $vars['H1'];
$h2           = $vars['H2'];

//could possibly use extract($vars); instead
```

Comment: PHP_SELF did it. Thanks Abra.

Comment: Good answer.  Yeah, the problem doesn't appear to be in the array like the OP is thinking.  More of the matching with `strpos` to the page name.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your pathes are correct, check output of `print(__FILE__);` `print($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` from index.php.

Try building your path with `__FILE__` and [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php). Maybe [realpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) is required to ensure path structure.

Also it is a good idea to not simply set $meta in a file, but instead return a generated array of the content like:
     array(
            'title' => 'Title text',
            'kexwords' => 'kexwords text',
            'description' => 'description text',
            // ...
        ),
        'ABOUT' => array(
            'title' => 'Title text',
            'kexwords' => 'kexwords text',
            'description' => 'description text',
            // ...
        ),
        'SERVICES' => array(
            'title' => 'Title text',
            'kexwords' => 'kexwords text',
            'description' => 'description text',
            // ...
        ),
        // ...
    );

and in other files

```
<?php
//file index.php
$meta = include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/seo.php' );
```

both ways should work tough.